# Python 3 regex remove characters before certain point

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have multiple words stored in a list like this:

```
31547   4.7072% i
25109   3.7466% u
20275   3.0253% you
10992   1.6401% me
9490    1.4160% do
7681    1.1461% like
6293    0.9390% want
6225    0.9288% my
5459    0.8145% have
5141    0.7671% your
```

now i need to cleanse this so that it removes everything before the (i) taking into account that the word will not always be (i) but the format of everything before will be similar. I have seen other questions that are similar but they needed the word/str to be same every time to work.

Thanks in advance for all help and advice, I have tried reading up and doing tutorials on Regex but i do find it quite complex to get your head around.

for a similar problem i had i needed to remove everything inside of brackets for which i used:

```
Cleanse = re.sub('<.*?>', '', line)
```

but I'm unsure as how to manipulate this to remove everything before the word as I will stress this is my first real time of coming across using regex.

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you have tried to use to solve this problem.

Comment: **the format of everything before will be similar** - an exact description of that format will help us to provide a well working answer and might be enough for yourself to build a regex from it. A single line of input makes it very hard to guess that exact format.

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'^\d+[ \t]+\d+\.\d+%[ \t]*', '', s, flags=re.M)`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/c9NdCq/2). If you are processing the text line by line, there is no need using `re.M`.

Comment: Did you see the result pane at https://regex101.com/r/c9NdCq/2? I will post if it is what you need.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, the demo is really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process a multiline string, you may use

```
s = re.sub(r'^\d+[ \t]+\d+\.\d+%[ \t]*', '', s, flags=re.M)
```

If you process line by line, use

```
r = re.compile(r'^\d+\s+\d+\.\d+%\s*')
...
s = r.sub('', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c9NdCq/2)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `^` - start of a string (or line if `re.M` flag is passed)
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `\d+\.\d+` - 1+ digits, `.`, 1+ digits
- `%` - a literal `%` symbol
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

Note that in a "multiline" version, the `[ \t]` is preferable in order to only match *horizontal* ASCII whitespace. It can also be done with a more sophisticated `[^\S\r\n]` pattern that is Unicode aware  by default in Python 3.x.

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks so much it's easy to read and understand